# Data-agnostic measure of spread?

Tags: python, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

I am attempting to split a number `v` into `n` roughly-equal sized parts. For example,

- splitting 100 into 4 parts could return `[27, 22, 26, 25]`
- splitting 160 into 5 parts could return `[36, 37, 32, 29, 26]`.

The interface of my function is as follows:

```py
def split(v, n, t)
```

"Roughly equal-sized" is vague, so I am attempting to devise a method by which I can mathematically describe this. That is what `t` is for. `t` would be a *tolerance*, a numerical value.

I had one idea about what this tolerance could be -- the maximum standard deviation of the data. I used Python's [`statistics.pstdev`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.pstdev) for this.

However, if I double every data value, then `pstdev` also doubles. This is not my desired behaviour -- for some `t`, `split(100, 10, t)` should act similar to `split(200, 10, t)`, only where each output value is doubled. If I used `pstdev`, then I would have to use `t * 2` for the latter function call to get the same "spread", so to speak.

So, is there some measure of spread that is divorced from the actual values of the data?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the data to percentages and then sum up the absolute values or squares of the differences to uniformity, i.e., with absolute values (27, 22, 26, 25) would give $0.02+0.03+0.01+0=0.06$ (all the summed up values are differences to 0.25), or with squares $0.02^2+0.03^2+0.01^2+0=0.0014$; you may want to take the square root for interpretation in terms of the original values. Based on squares your measure will be more dominated by the biggest deviations than if you took absolute values.

There are several ways of doing this that all do slightly different things, and it depends on what exactly you want. Also, you will have to define your tolerance level on your own, as the data can't know how much you tolerate. (A statistical way of doing this would be to test uniformity by a $\chi^2$-test, however this would reject uniformity more easily for larger $v$, which I gather you don't want.)